# Can't install any library via pip SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED

Tags: python, ssl, pip, certificate

So I've been struggling few days trying to fix this error that does not allow me to install any kind of library using pip install. I've been looking for 3+ google pages for solutions but they didn't work.

The error is:

```
yusepp@pop-os:~/Desktop$ pip install opencv-python
Collecting opencv-python
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:1131)'))': /packages/67/50/665a503167396ad347957bea0bd8d5c08c865030b2d1565ff06eba613780/opencv_python-4.5.5.64-cp36-abi3-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:1131)'))': /packages/67/50/665a503167396ad347957bea0bd8d5c08c865030b2d1565ff06eba613780/opencv_python-4.5.5.64-cp36-abi3-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:1131)'))': /packages/67/50/665a503167396ad347957bea0bd8d5c08c865030b2d1565ff06eba613780/opencv_python-4.5.5.64-cp36-abi3-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:1131)'))': /packages/67/50/665a503167396ad347957bea0bd8d5c08c865030b2d1565ff06eba613780/opencv_python-4.5.5.64-cp36-abi3-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:1131)'))': /packages/67/50/665a503167396ad347957bea0bd8d5c08c865030b2d1565ff06eba613780/opencv_python-4.5.5.64-cp36-abi3-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /packages/67/50/665a503167396ad347957bea0bd8d5c08c865030b2d1565ff06eba613780/opencv_python-4.5.5.64-cp36-abi3-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:1131)')))
```

I tried:

- `--trusted-host or adding them into` .pip/pip.conf` file: this changed the error to **ERROR: THESE PACKAGES DO NOT MATCH THE HASHES FROM THE REQUIREMENTS FILE**. Which I also tried to fix by applying --no-cache-dir without success.
- Change time zone, update time zone, synchronize timezone, try utc mode.
- Reinstall python/conda from 0.
- Reinstall pip.

Nothing it's working. I'm on Pop!_OS 21.10 and never experienced this error.

Comment: You mention conda, is this in a conda environment? There does not seem to be the ususal `(envname)` prefix to your command prompt.

Comment: @FlyingTeller yes this is a conda env, I skipped the starting (envname) but yeah it's there!